# How do I find the expected return on a ticket?

Tags: statistics, central-tendency

A lottery has a grand prize of 400,000 dollars, five runner up prizes of 50,000 dollars each, nine third-place prizes of 10000 dollars each, and twenty-five consolation prizes of 1000 dollars each. If 2,000,000 tickets are sold for 1 dollar each and the probability of any one ticket winning is the same as that of any other ticket winning, find the expected return on a $1 ticket. (Round your answer to two decimal places.)

I tried 
$$(400,000\times \frac {1}{2,000,000}) + (50,000\times \frac {5}{2,000,000}) +
(10,000\times \frac {9}{2,000,000}) + (1,000\times \frac{25}{2,000,000})$$

and so on with each of the other prizes, getting .3825 then round it to .38 which was wrong.

Please explain what I may have done wrong or show me what I would need to do instead. Thanks.

Comment: Did you account for the fact there are multiple runner up prizes in  each category?

Comment: What is the "right" answer?

Comment: I think expected return is usually a percentage of the original investment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your value of $.3825$ is correct for not taking into account the amount paid for the ticket.

So I think your expected value is  $.3825-1=-\$0.6175$

Comment: Does the OP's wording, " expected return on a $1 ticket" support your interpretation?  Probably you're right and the question is poorly phrased...)

Comment: @DJohnM: Considering that the OP did the math correctly (for the return not counting the ticket cost) but said the answer was 'wrong', I thought counting the cost of the ticket seemed like the most reasonable thing to do.